Parametric noise over Input noise
I came across this research from 2017 that talked about using "Parametric noise" instead of input based noise. I have tried to have it in my PPO based Boid flocking custom environment but came to conclude it ain't possible, cause it ain't supported in SB3.
Any suggestions on how I can add or use it. I think it needs open ai baselines, even then how does one go about it cause found no documentation for now and are there any environment limitations, like where we can't use it?
Better exploration with parameter noise

you can use a custom policy network where you define everything (and thus you can add the noise to the parameters) https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/custom_policy.html

Thanks, that's interesting I'll read the paper and try it. Tried custom policy earlier in another scenario, failed lol.

Yeah ST3 is not the most flexible library in the world ahah
